# Global navigation key with GoRouter and Riverpod Providers

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-go-router

I combined Firebase auth, riverpod, and Gorouter via Luca Venir's [repository here](https://github.com/lucavenir/go_router_riverpod/tree/master/firebase_example). It really works great. Now my issue is that I'm making a web app, and I don't know how to access the GoRouter routes that are inside the routerProvider to change the page when the user clicks on a nav item. It seems like a simple issue, but I've had problems with navigation and global keys before.

I've abbreviated my code to what I believe are the most essential parts, but let me know if more is needed. My routerProvider is based on my auth repo, which utilizes Firebase.

```
`final routerProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final authState = ref.watch(authStateProvider);

  return GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: key,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    initialLocation: SplashPage.routeLocation,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: SplashPage.routeLocation,
        name: SplashPage.routeName,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return const SplashPage();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/preloginhome',
        name: 'preloginhome',
        builder: (context, state) {
          return const PreLoginHome();
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        builder: (context, state) {
          return const Dashboard();
        },
      ),
      //more code
```

The main app watches the above routerProvider
`

```
class MyAppWithFirebase extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyAppWithFirebase({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final router = ref.watch(routerProvider);
    return MaterialApp.router(
      theme: CustomTheme.darkTheme,
      routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}
```

Now my questoion is, how can I navigate with the routes declared in routerProvider? My custom app bar is something like this but I'm missing something..

```
class CustomAppBar extends ConsumerWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CustomAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final router = ref.watch(routerProvider);
    final isUserSignedIn = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null;
    return AppBar(
      title: TextButton(
        onPressed: isUserSignedIn
            ? () {
                key.currentState!.pushNamed(Dashboard.routeLocation);
              }
            : () {
                key.currentState!.pushNamed('/preloginhome');
              },
        child: Text(
          'Agroopet',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22,
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Just don't know how to properly access the routes in the routerProvider and also am incorrectly setting the global nav key.

With the above code I get the error

> "Another exception was thrown: Navigator.onGenerateRoute was null, but
> the route named "/preloginhome" was referenced."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question wasn't even framed in the right way. I've made some progress now when I'm able to navigate *when I'm logged in* (I was testing while not authenticated) by calling the routerProvider like so:

```
 onPressed: isUserSignedIn
            ? () => ref.read(routerProvider).go(Dashboard.routeLocation)
            : () {
                ref.read(routerProvider).go(PreLoginHome.routeLocation);
              },
```

Now it seems like the issue is in my own AuthChecker class because I can't go anywhere besides the login screen when the user isn't authenticated.

```
class AuthChecker extends ConsumerWidget {
  const AuthChecker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final authState = ref.watch(authStateProvider);
    return authState.when(
        data: (user) {
          if (user != null) return const Dashboard();
          return const LoginPage();
        },
        loading: () => const LoadingScreen(),
        error: (e, trace) => ErrorScreen(e, trace));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation, to navigate to a page, use can use `GoRouter.of(context).go('/page2')` or `context.go('/page2')` or `context.push('/page2')`

check out this [docs here](https://docs.page/csells/go_router)

Comment: The thing is is that it's wrapped within a GoRouter provider, doing it as you suggest simpoly doesn't work